.sh file to check if file exists with dynamic name
I created a sample .sh file with script like this:
if [ -f "/Spool/Cognos/Cognos.xlsx" ]
then 
    echo "File exists"

else
  echo "File not exists"
fi

However, I would like to change so that it could read file with dynamic names, the files that will be uploaded in the folder /Spool/Cognos will be something like this:
Cognos Aug24.xlsx,
Cognos Sep24.xlsx,
Cognos July24.xlsx, etc.
How can I change the if part of the script above? I tried
if [ -f "/Spool/Cognos/Cognos*.xlsx" ] with * as wildcard but it seems like it does not work.

Are you in a POSIX shell (sh) not having the regular bash shell?

You need to define first the desired behavious when you have more than one matching file, for instance CognosChristmas.xlsx and CognosEaster.xlsx.

Don't use .sh suffixes on your filenames: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

You can do it like this:
for f in /Spool/Cognos/Cognos*.xlsx; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo File exists
  else
    echo File not exists
  fi
  break
done

If you don't mind overwriting the positional parameters, this will also work:
set -- /Spool/Cognos/Cognos*.xlsx
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
  echo File exists
else
  echo File not exists
fi


Perhaps also explain that  * is not a wildcard when it is between quotes.
